# SQL Server 2016 Express Install - R Services Install Failed

Tags: sql-server-2016

OS: Windows  10 64 Bit

I ran the SQL Server 2016 Express ISO setup. All the components installed except for R Services. I guess it couldn't download that installation package from destination. When I connect to this instance via SSMS and click on Polybase, I get the following error.

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PolybaseManagement)

How can I rectify this? Please advise. Repair SQL Server instance also didn't work.

Extract from RSetup Log file.

2018-04-10T06:30:24 INFO    Command invoked: E:\Dev Tools\en_sql_server_2016_express_with_advanced_services_with_service_pack_1_x64_9540756\x64\RSetup.exe /install /component SRS /version 8.0.3.15000 /language 1033 /destdir C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS\R_SERVICES /logfile C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20180410_114432\RSetup.log /instance SQLEXPRESS
2018-04-10T06:30:24 INFO    Searching for cache dir: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Setup Bootstrap\R_SERV_CACHE
2018-04-10T06:30:24 INFO    Using default cache dir: C:\Users\balaji.v\AppData\Local\Temp\
2018-04-10T06:30:24 INFO    Backing up source dir: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS\R_SERVICES\ => C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS\R_SERVICES_4d040c58-b12e-414b-82d1-5a11dde969b7
2018-04-10T06:30:24 ERROR   Error renaming source dir: Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS\R_SERVICES\' is denied.
2018-04-10T06:30:24 INFO    Exiting with code 5

---

Feature:                       R Services (In-Database)
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Component error code:          0x84B40002
  Error description:             The SQL Server feature 'sql_inst_mr' is not in a supported state for repair, as it was never successfully configured. Only features from successful installations can be repaired. To continue, remove the specified SQL Server feature.
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=13.0.4001.0&EvtType=0x2841E06E%401204%402&EvtType=0x2841E06E%401204%402

Feature:                       SQL Server Replication

Thanks
Balaji.V

Comment: You say: "All the components installed except for R Services. I guess it couldn't download that installation package from destination" what makes you say it couldn't download the installation package? Cause, if it couldn't dl the package, that would explain the error message.

Comment: There was a window during installation that said, 'R' related stuff would be downloaded and asked me the check the agreement and proceed. So my guess was the download couldnt happen and hence the installation failed. Now the issue here is that repair option doesnt seem to retry the download and install it and give a successful install. Any thoughts @NielsBerglund